# Combinatorics - how many possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

How many possibilities do we have to solve this equation?

1. all variables are natural numbers.
2. $a$ is an odd number.
3. $a + b + c + d + e = 10$

Comment: Do you regard zero as a natural number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to count out how many ways 5 natural numbers can add up to 10:

Write out ten "$1$"s, separated by dots:
$$
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
$$
There are nine dots between the "$1$"s.  Pick four of them and replace with slashes  For example:
$$
1.1.1|1.1.1|1|1|1.1
$$
Count up the ones between slashes, and those are your a,b,c,d,e.  The set above yields: $(a,b,c,d,e) = (3,3,1,1,2)$.

Since you picked four dots out of nine, there are ${9\choose4} = 126$ ways to do this.

However, this ignores constraint 2: "a is an odd number". Adding that in complicates the problem a little.  So we solve for $a = 1,3,5$ and the other four numbers add up to $9,7,5$.  Using the same technique as above, we choose $3$ dots from $8, 6,$ or $4$:
$$
{8\choose3} + {6\choose 3} + {4\choose 3} = 56 + 20 + 4 = 80.
$$
$80$ is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Considering natural numbers as $\{1,2,3...\}$

Write it as $2A-1+b+c+d+e=10$ where all are natural numbers.
You want solutions for :

$$2A+b+c+d+e=11$$

$$b+c+d+e=11-2A$$

Write your $RHS$ as sum of $1+1+1...1$. You can choose any four of the plus signs and whatever that comes in between forms your $b,c,d,e$ accordingly. Hence : $\binom{11-2A-1}{4-1}=\binom{10-2A}{3}$

As $A$ varies from $3$ to $1$, your answer is $\sum_{a=1}^{a=3}\binom{10-2A}{3} $. You can calculate that.

Comment: can you explain more about how you made this multinomial theorem equation? and why A varies between 1 and 3?

Comment: @user144555 Edited.